# Why am i seeing different behaviour when wrapping this utility type in another?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I came across these 2 solutions for testing equality in types.

```
// @link https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

type Equals<X, Y> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

```
// @link https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-931205995

type EqualsWrapped<T> = T extends infer R & {} ?
    { [P in keyof R]: R[P] }
    : never

type EqualsV2<A, B> =
    (<T>() => T extends EqualsWrapped<A> ? 1 : 2) extends
        (<T>() => T extends EqualsWrapped<B> ? 1 : 2)
        ? true
        : false
```

I've just been testing them out on something i'm working on and even though they work as expected when called directly, i was surprised/confused to find that they don't appear to work as expected when wrapped in another utility type.

```
type ToTuple<Type1, Type2> = [Type1, Type2]


// Equals

type test1 = Equals<[unknown, never], [unknown, never]> // true


type TestFunction<Type1, Type2> = Equals<[Type1, Type2], [unknown, never]>


type test2 = TestFunction<unknown, never> // false - would have expected this to also be true?

type test3 = Equals<ToTuple<unknown, never>, [unknown, never]> // true



// Equals2

type test4 = EqualsV2<[unknown, never], [unknown, never]> // true


type TestFunction2<Type1, Type2> = EqualsV2<[Type1, Type2], [unknown, never]>


type test5 = TestFunction2<unknown, never> // false - would have expected this to also be true?

type test6 = EqualsV2<ToTuple<unknown, never>, [unknown, never]>
```

Could someone please explain why i'm seeing this behaviour?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/PTAEAEBsEsDsGtQAsAuKAOBnAXCA5tCkgK4BGAdAMYD2AtsLdJQE7WbUBmKwAKgJ7oApgGUW0dN2iZMxQZmAAmAOwAGBQBYAxFJmCatWoNgoAtOoUBGAKwKAnADYrKgLAAoNygGDQAUQCOxACGkJgAPAAaADSgAJoAfKAAvG6gqaAAFKE8cekAlEkJPKCCAB4oRgAmmKDhoAD8oBag2KAK%20aXlsFUpaZnZeQWgRR2V1TH1jc2t%20Q0ozLJTHMGYggDcbhuuIBAwCMhoWLjABERkVHQMTKzsXLxeosziktKy8spqWjqy%20obGJrYAZgsChUVlstism08Ql8AWWAHVmIF0EIKlkEokhsUyqNQHAOIJmKAAEqgABkoAA3gBfeo9VKU0AAbQACnjYKB4II%20JwSQBdFrE1l80DU%20lTWCCABuhKhXlhQRCADUFKEAILRABCGPFfRy%20UShWxnSqCoRSJRgjRaoSDSaLTaxtG4rSGXRA0NWJGXWq-kVmERyNRoW1E3t0xdaVm80EkdSLSWIVj7hTbhA6Yzmaz2Zzubz%20fzcphPGoPGI6EggiyXgs0X4QgUGOZ9cEtaGXgUfM2abAfuWRe85UwKCamL7IVCTOICFg1AA7rBopKZcw%20dEpzP54vQMvCXyEts5gtu65od4eHIUAAxaeUFDQaiwatCNstxtJM0Tpkt18dtfM6d4FnBcl2lPc4hPM9QCHFAFA-C9hxvWA7wfJ9AOA7dd2YA8wETFZQBMUA52oYhIAqZBAhlbEhDvK1oKQKRoOoUBlmY0hBxjOoB2gy8AQ-ccwhLMsKyrdCt1Alc4nXMSQJ3MDVwg1MU22ASFG4mD1H4uFlVVDcgPEuSV3-PSMIk8DQEPGNQEg%20UEOvW970fVUfzrDsmwElVJxc9sG2MmTMPk-cbJhGCrHgy8kJQpzQn8szsIs3Dlm8QjiNI8ikEo7xSho8pyKIRiUGY1jQHY6DOPUy97C0-1PKE8tKxizdZKwqSAKagKjLiIA)

Comment: `TestFunction<T, U>` is being eagerly reduced to `false` right in its definition without waiting for  `T` or `U` to be specified.  This reminds me of [ms/TS#41613](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41613), but it's not the same exact issue (since that one has been fixed).  I don't know if I can explain why this happens without either finding an existing bug report or filing a new one.  If nobody else can find what's going on, you might want to open one yourself, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, i've submitted this [issue #46867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46867)